# prometheus alert manager config not showing in UI

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I am add prometheus(prom/prometheus:v2.16.0) alertmanager,now I add rule config in prometheus-configmap.xml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: prometheus-config
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: EnsureExists
data:
  prometheus.yml: |
    rule_files:
    - /etc/prometheus/rules.yml

    alerting:
      alertmanagers:
        - static_configs:
          - targets: ["alertmanager:9093"]

    scrape_configs:
    - job_name: traefik
      metrics_path: /metrics
      static_configs:
      - targets:
        - traefik.kube-system.svc.cluster.local:8080

  rules.yml: |
    groups:
    - name: test-rule
      rules:
      - alert: NodeFilesystemUsage
        expr: (node_filesystem_size{device="rootfs"} - node_filesystem_free{device="rootfs"}) / node_filesystem_size{device="rootfs"} * 100 > 80
        for: 2m
        labels:
          team: node
        annotations:
          summary: "{{$labels.instance}}: High Filesystem usage detected"
          description: "{{$labels.instance}}: Filesystem usage is above 80% (current value is: {{ $value }}"
```

and I refresh the config:

```
kubectl apply -f prometheus-configmap.xm
kubectl exec -it soa-room-service-686959b94d-9g5q2 /bin/bash
curl -X POST http://prometheus.kube-system.svc.cluster.local:9090/-/reload
```

the prometheus dashboard config shows like this:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 1m
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  evaluation_interval: 1m
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets:
      - alertmanager:9093
    scheme: http
    timeout: 10s
    api_version: v1
rule_files:
- /etc/prometheus/rules.yml
scrape_configs:
- job_name: traefik
  honor_timestamps: true
  scrape_interval: 1m
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: http
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - traefik.kube-system.svc.cluster.local:8080
```

the alert config rules not valid,what should I do to make it works?

[image]

This is how to install prometheus :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: prometheus
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: prometheus
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
    version: v2.2.1
spec:
  serviceName: "prometheus"
  replicas: 1
  podManagementPolicy: "Parallel"
  updateStrategy:
   type: "RollingUpdate"
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: prometheus
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: prometheus
      annotations:
        scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod: ''
    spec:
      priorityClassName: system-cluster-critical
      serviceAccountName: prometheus
      initContainers:
      - name: "init-chown-data"
        image: "busybox:latest"
        imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
        command: ["chown", "-R", "65534:65534", "/data"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: prometheus-data
          mountPath: /data
          subPath: ""
      containers:
        - name: prometheus-server-configmap-reload
          image: "jimmidyson/configmap-reload:v0.1"
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          args:
            - --volume-dir=/etc/config
            - --webhook-url=http://localhost:9090/-/reload
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config-volume
              mountPath: /etc/config
              readOnly: true
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 10m
              memory: 10Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 10m
              memory: 10Mi

        - name: prometheus-server
          image: "prom/prometheus:v2.16.0"
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          args:
            - --config.file=/etc/config/prometheus.yml
            - --storage.tsdb.path=/data
            - --web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries
            - --web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles
            - --web.enable-lifecycle
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9090
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /-/ready
              port: 9090
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 30
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /-/healthy
              port: 9090
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 30
          # based on 10 running nodes with 30 pods each
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 200m
              memory: 1000Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 200m
              memory: 1000Mi

          volumeMounts:
            - name: config-volume
              mountPath: /etc/config
            - name: prometheus-data
              mountPath: /data
              subPath: ""
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: prometheus-config
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: prometheus-data
    spec:
      storageClassName: standard
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: "16Gi"
```

This is my pod describe output:

```
 kubectl describe pods prometheus-0 -n kube-system

Name:                 prometheus-0
Namespace:            kube-system
Priority:             2000000000
Priority Class Name:  system-cluster-critical
Node:                 azshara-k8s01/172.19.104.231
Start Time:           Wed, 11 Mar 2020 19:28:28 +0800
Labels:               controller-revision-hash=prometheus-cf5dc9d8b
                      k8s-app=prometheus
                      statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=prometheus-0
Annotations:          scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod:
Status:               Running
IP:                   172.30.224.4
IPs:                  <none>
Controlled By:        StatefulSet/prometheus
Init Containers:
  init-chown-data:
    Container ID:  docker://a3adc4bce1dccbdd6adb27ca38c54b7ae670d605b6273d53e85f601649357709
    Image:         busybox:latest
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://busybox@sha256:b26cd013274a657b86e706210ddd5cc1f82f50155791199d29b9e86e935ce135
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      chown
      -R
      65534:65534
      /data
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Wed, 11 Mar 2020 19:28:29 +0800
      Finished:     Wed, 11 Mar 2020 19:28:29 +0800
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /data from prometheus-data (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from prometheus-token-k8d22 (ro)
Containers:
  prometheus-server-configmap-reload:
    Container ID:  docker://9d31d10c9246ddfa94d84d59737edd03f06e008960657b000461ae886d030516
    Image:         jimmidyson/configmap-reload:v0.1
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://jimmidyson/configmap-reload@sha256:2d40c2eaa6f435b2511d0cfc5f6c0a681eeb2eaa455a5d5ac25f88ce5139986e
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Args:
      --volume-dir=/etc/config
      --webhook-url=http://localhost:9090/-/reload
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 11 Mar 2020 19:28:30 +0800
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     10m
      memory:  10Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        10m
      memory:     10Mi
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/config from config-volume (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from prometheus-token-k8d22 (ro)
  prometheus-server:
    Container ID:  docker://65d2870debb187a20a102786cac3725745e5bc0d60f3e04cb38c2beea6f5c128
    Image:         prom/prometheus:v2.16.0
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://prom/prometheus@sha256:e4ca62c0d62f3e886e684806dfe9d4e0cda60d54986898173c1083856cfda0f4
    Port:          9090/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Args:
      --config.file=/etc/config/prometheus.yml
      --storage.tsdb.path=/data
      --web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries
      --web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles
      --web.enable-lifecycle
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 11 Mar 2020 19:28:30 +0800
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     200m
      memory:  1000Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        200m
      memory:     1000Mi
    Liveness:     http-get http://:9090/-/healthy delay=30s timeout=30s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:    http-get http://:9090/-/ready delay=30s timeout=30s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /data from prometheus-data (rw)
      /etc/config from config-volume (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from prometheus-token-k8d22 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  prometheus-data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  prometheus-data-prometheus-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  config-volume:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      prometheus-config
    Optional:  false
  prometheus-token-k8d22:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  prometheus-token-k8d22
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Guaranteed
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 360s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 360s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From                    Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----                    -------
  Normal  Scheduled  50m   default-scheduler       Successfully assigned kube-system/prometheus-0 to azshara-k8s01
  Normal  Pulled     50m   kubelet, azshara-k8s01  Container image "busybox:latest" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    50m   kubelet, azshara-k8s01  Created container init-chown-data
  Normal  Started    50m   kubelet, azshara-k8s01  Started container init-chown-data
  Normal  Pulled     50m   kubelet, azshara-k8s01  Container image "jimmidyson/configmap-reload:v0.1" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    50m   kubelet, azshara-k8s01  Created container prometheus-server-configmap-reload
  Normal  Started    50m   kubelet, azshara-k8s01  Started container prometheus-server-configmap-reload
  Normal  Pulled     50m   kubelet, azshara-k8s01  Container image "prom/prometheus:v2.16.0" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    50m   kubelet, azshara-k8s01  Created container prometheus-server
  Normal  Started    50m   kubelet, azshara-k8s01  Started container prometheus-server
```

Comment: how did you installed Prometheus?

Comment: I am install it as stateful set

Comment: if it is deployed using Prometheus-operator, then you need to create an prometheusrule object. once you create an prometheusrule object it will automatically pick the new alerts rule. below is the sample:

Comment: I pasted the pod describe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have some possible way of checking your configuration.

- https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/configuration/ (check documentation and try to run alertmanager in console on your computer to see log messages during startup)
- https://prometheus.io/webtools/alerting/routing-tree-editor/ (visualization for alerting routes, can be handy. parsing error can be seen by wrong visualization)
- https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/issues/333 (tool for checking config directly)

I am not familiar with your kubernates set-up, so I am not able to verify it for you. I hope my links will help

Answer (score 1):

if it is deployed using Prometheus-operator, then you need to create an prometheusrule object. once you create an prometheusrule object it will automatically pick the new alerts rule. below is the sample:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PrometheusRule
metadata:
  labels:
    prometheus: service-prometheus
    role: alert-rules
  name: prometheus-service-rules
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  groups:
  - name: general.rules
    rules:
    - alert: TargetDown-serviceprom
      annotations:
        description: '{{ $value }}% of {{ $labels.job }} targets are down.'
        summary: Targets are down
      expr: 100 * (count(up == 0) BY (job) / count(up) BY (job)) > 10
      for: 10m
      labels:
        severity: warning
    - alert: DeadMansSwitch-serviceprom
      annotations:
        description: This is a DeadMansSwitch meant to ensure that the entire Alerting
          pipeline is functional.
        summary: Alerting DeadMansSwitch
      expr: vector(1)
      labels:
        severity: none
```

Comment: I am not deploy it using Prometheus-operator,thank you for your advice.@chitender kumar

Answer (score 1):

The rule.yml file in the path `/etc/config`,not in the `/etc/prometheus`,so change the rules file read path,the rules path config like this:

```
rule_files:
    - /etc/config/rules.yml
```